# How to return a function's arguments from **args

Tags: python, parameters, arguments

Say I have a function:

```
def function(arg1, arg2, **args):
    panda = arg.get('panda', None)
```

How do I find the miscellaneous arguments from **args that weren't processed by the function? For instance if I accidentally passed 'pandas' or 'pand' , how would I find and print pandas / pand?

Comment: What is wrong with `panda = args.get('panda')`?

Comment: Why do you not know what arguments the function takes, and why would it matter if you did?

Comment: So I can raise an error if one of the arguments is unrecognized by the function

Answer (score 0):

You need a set of arguments that your function expects (let's say, `my_args`). Then you can subtract it from the set of passed arguments. The difference set contains the unexpected arguments:

```
def foobar(**args):
    my_args = set(['foo','bar','panda']) # Expected arguments
    unknown = set(args) - my_args
    print(unknown) # Or raise an exception

foobar(foo=1,bar=2,foobar=3,pandas="hello!")
# {'pandas','foobar'}
```